# Python script gets frozen when calls a bash script

Tags: python, bash, flask

I have a flask app that calls a python function, my_funct.py, which has this code:

```
container_logs = 'bash train.sh'
subprocess.call([container_logs],shell=True)
return result
```

The issue is that my_funct.py gets frozen at the subprocess line:

```
subprocess.call([container_logs],shell=True)
```

In consequence, my flask app gets frozen too, waiting for a response:

```
resp = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers )
```

I know that the process called from "bash train.sh" has finished since I get the output file, but the script keeps waiting indefinitely

**EDIT**

The script last about 10min running when I call **bash train.sh** directly from the terminal.

[image]

I'm adding this at the end to the script:

```
echo 'done'

exit 0

echo 'has not exit'
```

In the terminal  I get the "Done" print and not the "has no exit", from there I assume the script is finishing:
[image]

[image]

But the issue from the API side remains.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: are you sure that the bash script actually has finished? That it's not waiting for some input before closing down or anything? Just that it gives output doesn't have to mean it is finished ;)

Comment: Also, do you use `exit 0` at the end of the Bash script?

Comment: @SimonKlaver Yes, I'm sure i just added a screenshot at the end of the question

Comment: @Bayou No, I'm not using exit 0 anywhere, not sure where it should be.

Comment: From the screenshot, looks like the script generate lot of output, including progress bar. You might have to consume the output (or redirect to a different file) to allow the script to complete.

Comment: **Please don't post screen shots;** provide the text in the screen shots as actual text instead. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: There is no need to explicitly `exit 0`; the shell will terminate with the exit code from the last command executed when it reaches the end of the script.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is *probably* in how you are calling the script, but we can't tell without seeing the script.

In the meantime, this is certainly an error:

```
subprocess.call(['bash train.sh'],shell=True)
```

You want either

```
subprocess.call(['bash', 'train.sh'])  # shell=False
```

or

```
subprocess.call('bash train.sh',shell=True)
```

You can't combine a list with `shell=True` because the shell expects a string, not a list, as the command sequence to run.

If your script is executable and has a valid shebang, you actually want

```
subprocess.call(['train.sh'])
```

There is no way Bash can set the Python variable `result` without cooperation from the calling Python program.

If your script attempts to read from standard input, maybe try

```
subprocess.call(['train.sh'], stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

If your script attempts to write something to standard output, maybe try

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['train.sh'])
```

This is all just speculative; your question should probably be closed as unclear, but at the very least this should give you something more to update your question and/or your code with.